PetaPoco SQL Union Statement not working in .NET
The SQL statement is working fine in SSMS, but when I apply it in .NET Framework using PetaPoco.SQL, it keeps having error saying:

All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Tested:

The datatypes of each column I've ensured it is correct.
The number of columns in each SELECT statement are 14.
Without "UNION", each SELECT statement can query data without errors.

Codes in .NET(Backend):
Sql sql = Sql.Builder;
sql.Select("GC.CategoryName AS Category, GP.ProviderName, GN.en AS GameName, GA.HasBuyFreeSpin, GA.HasFeatureGames," +
    "GA.HasJackpot, GA.EXclusive, GA.MEgaways, GA.Volatility, GA.RTP, GA.MInBet, GA.MAxBet," +
    "GP.Id AS GameProviderId, GC.Id AS GameCategoryId");
sql.From("afbGameAttribute GA WITH(NOLOCK)");
sql.InnerJoin("dbo.afbGameProvider GP WITH(NOLOCK) ON GA.GameProviderId = GP.Id");
sql.InnerJoin("dbo.afbGameCategory GC WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.GameCategoryId = GC.Id");
sql.InnerJoin("Language.dbo.GameName GN WITH(NOLOCK) ON GA.GameName = GN.key2");
if (param.f != null)
{
    if (param.f.CategoryId > 0) { sql.Where("GC.Id = @0", param.f.CategoryId); }
    if (param.f.ProviderId > 0) { sql.Where("GP.Id = @0", param.f.ProviderId); }
    if (param.f.GameName != null) { sql.Where("GN.en LIKE @0", "%" + param.f.GameName + "%"); }
}
sql.Append(" UNION ");
sql.Select("GC.CategoryName AS Category, GP.ProviderName, GN.en AS GameName, " +
    "CAST(NULL AS TINYINT) AS HasBuyFreeSpin, CAST(NULL AS TINYINT) AS HasFeatureGames, CAST(NULL AS TINYINT) AS HasJackpot, CAST(NULL AS TINYINT) AS EXclusive, CAST(NULL AS TINYINT) AS MEgaways, CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS Volatility, CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL) AS RTP, CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(12,4)) AS MInBet, CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(12,4)) AS MAxBet," +
    "GP.Id AS GameProviderId, GC.Id AS GameCategoryId");
sql.From("afbGame G WITH(NOLOCK)");
sql.InnerJoin("dbo.afbGameProvider GP WITH(NOLOCK) ON G.GameProviderId = GP.Id");
sql.InnerJoin("dbo.afbGameCategory GC WITH(NOLOCK) ON G.GameCategoryId = GC.Id");
sql.InnerJoin("Language.dbo.GameName GN WITH(NOLOCK) ON G.GameName = GN.key2");
sql.Where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM afbGameAttribute GA WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE GA.GameName = G.GameName)");
if (param.f != null)
{
    if (param.f.CategoryId > 0) { sql.Where("GC.Id = @0", param.f.CategoryId); }
    if (param.f.ProviderId > 0) { sql.Where("GP.Id = @0", param.f.ProviderId); }
    if (param.f.GameName != null) { sql.Where("GN.en LIKE @0", "%" + param.f.GameName + "%"); }
}
sql.OrderBy("GameName");

result.D = db.Page<GameAttribute>(param.p, param.n, sql);


Aside do you know that using nolock is bad practice and should only ever be used if you are very very sure you know what you are doing.

yes, i need union to prevent duplicated value and i prefer using nolock to avoid interrupting others accessing the table.

Could be a furphy error. Can you dump the generated T-SQL to the console to see what's actually going on?

Aside... you only need to specify column aliases in the first part of a union.

https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

(1) Triple check that you don't have a mix of TINYINT and BIT select items. The naming of your HasXxxxx columns would indicate a boolean value, which is typically stored as a BIT type.  (2) If that is not it, I suggest a divide and conquer approach. Remove about half of the select items from both queries and retest. Add or remove items until you have identified the (possibly just the first) offending select item.

I'm not sure why you're using a random ORM (and I use the term loosely), might as well just use the raw string and just use dapper for the parameter/mapping

Yeah I was wondering that myself, I can't see any value with this peta poke thing
